# Searchkick with ElasticSearch returns "Faraday::ConnectionFailed: execution expired"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I've been using the [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem with elasticsearch with no problems on a Rails 4.2.0 application. I have a single Video model using searchkick.

For some reason `rake searchkick:reindex:all` is now failing consistently with:

> Reindexing Video... rake aborted! Faraday::ConnectionFailed: execution
>   expired

I originally installed elasticsearch via `brew install elasticsearch`, which returns:

> Warning: elasticsearch-1.3.4 already installed

Is it likely that my elasticsearch installation/database has become corrupted? If so, what is the best way to refresh it?

As per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-delete-index.html I tried `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'` but this doesn't resolve the error.

This problem occurs on my Mac, as well as Elastic Beanstalk when I deploy this code to AWS (both were previously working correctly).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically after hours of struggling I found the answer minutes after posting the question...

As per https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/382 I added an initializer with:

```
Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: ["localhost:9200"], retry_on_failure: true, transport_options: {request: {timeout: 250}})
```

which seems to have solved the problem. I'll report back if it recurs.

Comment: FYI, on version 5+ of Searchkick, you should be able to set the timeout via `Searchkick.timeout` and then just pass `retry_on_failure: true` as part of the newly introduced `client_options`, as seen here: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/0d3b9389a1e4bc23d2cccd7b7c63c6d912e782e5/lib/searchkick.rb#L105

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines of code in config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb

`Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: ["localhost:9200"], retry_on_failure: true, transport_options: {request: {timeout: 250}})`

You can specify this according to Rails environment.

Comment: thanks - but I think that's basically exactly what I posted in 2015?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was with the missing port in the URL. ( I am using AWS elasticsearch and not running it on localhost. )

I changed

```
ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:elasticsearch, :url)
```

to

```
ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:elasticsearch, :url) + ':443'
```

This does not affect all my projects, so I am guessing this has to do with a newer release.