# Searchkick + ElasticSearch in Production: Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, searchkick

I have an application in production with ElasticSearch. (It works) but now I can add searchkick gem instead use only elasticsearch.

For this I added the following:

In my ***Gemfile*** added:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'searchkick'
```

In my ***config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb*** (I'm using Amazon Elasticsearch Service for production. Ok I know this is bad practices but I'll go change this for Environment variables)

```
if Rails.env == "production"
    Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/'

else
    Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'http://localhost:9200/'
end
```

in ***models/product.rb***

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  searchkick
  #currently use this function for search. (It works)
  scope :searching, ->(query) { __elasticsearch__.search(query).records }
end
```

but now when I try to use in the server:

```
Product.search("foobar") #before run: rails c production
```

Show me the next message: **Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2)**

After that I try this

```
rake searchkick:reindex:all RAILS_ENV=production
```

And I got the same message. Any idea for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I finished write this post I read this: [Searchkick with ElasticSearch returns "Faraday::ConnectionFailed: execution expired"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565919/searchkick-with-elasticsearch-returns-faradayconnectionfailed-execution-expi?rq=1)

in ***config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb***

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  url = 'http://myelasticsearch-xyz-foobar.amazonaws.com'
    Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: url
  Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: url, retry_on_failure: true, transport_options: {request: {timeout: 250}})
else
  url = 'http://localhost:9200/'
    Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: url
  Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: url, retry_on_failure: true, transport_options: {request: {timeout: 250}})
end
```

After refactoring and clean this code I got this:

```
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: env['RAILS_ENV']
  Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: env['RAILS_ENV'], retry_on_failure: true, transport_options: {request: {timeout: 250} })
```

I hope this explanation works for others

Comment: FYI you've left the connection details in the clear and your security groups appears to allow connections from anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I found the above answer to get me 95% of the way there.  I followed Nelson's advice and created an Elasticsearch initializer which eliminated the `Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200):`
However I still had to reindex and migrate my Heroku DB.

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=YOUR CLASS NAME
```

then `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Hope that clarifies for any Heroku newbies such as myself who got stuck on the last part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gem 'searchkick'` just add the below line in `/config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb`

```
ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "http://myelasticsearch-xyz-foobar.amazonaws.com:port"
```